# pass outfile to another program using bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I have the following bash code for a batch run of multiple files to be processed by 3 different programs:

```
for i in *.txt
do
program1 -in ${i} -out Prog1_out_${i}

program2 -in Prog1_out_${i} -out Prog2_out_${i}

program3 -in Prog2_out_${i} -out Prog3_out_${i}

done
```

I ran into problem with program 2 not finding the input which is the output from program 1, and of course program 3 did not find the required input.

Can anyone help with suggestions for solving the problem?

Thanks

Comment: You could look at using `wait` http://ss64.com/bash/wait.html

Comment: The first question to ask is : does "program1" produce the wanted output ? Does it do that by means of reaching its own ending, or does the output creation take more time than the script itself ? In other words, is a process forked to the background ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the programs produce the output whenever they are successful, you could make them dependent of the previous commands success, like this:

```
program1 -in ${i} -out Prog1_out_${i}   &&

program2 -in Prog1_out_${i} -out Prog2_out_${i} &&

program3 -in Prog2_out_${i} -out Prog3_out_${i}
```

So if one of the programs fails, the rest of the chain will not be invoked.

However, if the creation of the output has nothing to do with the success of the program, but you just want to check if the files exist, you can add the appropriate check before you call programx, i.e.

```
if [ -f "${i}" ]
then
    progx ...
fi
```

As you are doing the same thing all the time this could be generalized for all programs (untested):

```
for i in *.txt
do
    mv $i Prog0_out_$i
    for program in 0 1 2 
    do
        INFILE=Prog{$program}_out_${$i}
        if [ ! -r ${INFILE} ]
        then
            break
        fi
        program{$program} -in ${INFILE} -out "Prog{$program}_out_$((i+1))"
    done
done
```

Comment: thanks for your code and the explanations. I was able to use part of your code to solve the problem. Much appreciated!